# Receive data array from Wifi with netcat and UDP

Tags: udp, wifi, netcat, udpclient

Trying to interface a device using Wifi to receive data array.
Netcat is used and set up as

```
UDP_IP='abc.def.c.cde"
UDP_PORT=53
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)
dataarray,addr=sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

When I run, I have `Permission denied error` at `sock.bind()`.
This `UDP_IP='abc.def.c.cde" is taken from ifconfig for wifi`.

But I don't know port number exactly.
How do i know port number for Wifi interface using UDP and Netcat?

Comment: *"port number for Wifi interface"* - An interface does not have a port number. *"I don't know port number exactly"* - Simply choose an unused one if you control both client and server. The port number you use for recipient (bind) and sender (sendto) must be the same. *"I have Permission denied error at sock.bind()"* - Port numbers below 1024 can only be bound by root.

Comment: Yes thanks, i set bigger that 1024 and no more error.